# mat-table group row and apply color to alternate groups

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

What I want to do is:

- group data by date
- apply alternative colors to grouped data

The final output should be like this:

[image]

Code:

```
export class CompletedOrdersComponent{
    previousOrderDate: Date;
    alternateColors = ['light-gray-bg', 'white-bg'];
    colorIndex = 0;

    getColorClass(data) {
        if (data.orderCreatedDate != this.previousOrderDate) {
            this.colorIndex++;
            this.previousOrderDate = data.orderCreatedDate;
        }
        return this.alternateColors[this.colorIndex % 2];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8 mat-table parent-table">
<!-- columns definition -->
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr [ngClass]="getColorClass(element)" mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
        class="example-element-row" [class.example-expanded-row]="" (click)="toggleState1(element)">
    </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is `getColorClass()` is being called even after view rendering, and `colorIndex` values goes in thousands, how can I stop calling this after data is rendered, means if there are 5 rows then `getColorClass()` should be called only 5 times.

**How can I apply alternate colors to grouped data?**

Comment: I think that the best bet is **add a new property** of your data that takes value 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple solution is to add a new field to your data:

```
for(let i = 0; i < yourData.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    yourData[i].odd = true;
  } else if (yourData[i - 1].previousOrderDate === yourData[i].previousOrderDate)  {
    yourData[i].odd = yourData[i - 1].odd;    
  } else {
    yourData[i].odd = !yourData[i - 1].odd;    
  }
}
```

and in the template you can use that new field to set the css class:

```
<tr [ngClass]="element.odd ? 'light-gray-bg' : 'white-bg'" mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" ...></tr>
```

This is some quick and dirty and untested code but you should be able to adapt it to your need!

Comment: This will apply color to alternate rows, I need to apply alternate color based on last row data, please check img mentioned in the question

Comment: ah yes I have read the question too quickly. You should be able to access the previous line with something like `dataSource.data[dataIndex -1]`

Comment: but it will not apply alternate colors, if you have a workaround in your head, please update the answer.

Comment: @IrfanYusanif I have updated my answer with a new solution

Comment: @Chris thanks for the answers.I have one question in regards to the angular material table can you please help here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an

Comment: I have posted a reply on your other question. If you think the answers are working you can mark them as accepted :)